# How to access $toast in pinia Store?

Tags: vuejs3, toast, pinia

I am using **Vue 3** option API , **Pinia** and **@meforma/vue-toaster** .

i have imported toaster in main.js as document said and it works perfectly in components .

now i need to use it in Pinia Store like this

**store.js**

```
actions: {
    async login(data) {
      try {
        const res = await authService.login(data);
      
        if (res.data.msg == "success") {
        this.$toast.success("loged in successfully", {
              position: "bottom-right",
              duration: 3000,
              type: 'success',
            });
      }
        
      } catch (error) {
                  
        this.$toast.error(error.res.data.error, {
        position: "bottom-right",
         duration: 5000,
         type: 'error',
         });
         }
      }
    },
  }
```

But it doesn't work !

```
Can not read properties of undefined (reading 'success')
```

what's the problem ?

Comment: Don't use toast in your store, store is for state management. Rather create a getter for able to access the login state(from component) and depending on that call your toast in the components. You can use computed and mapgetters/mapstate for reactively fetching the auth state.

Comment: I   want to show error or success message after login with toast

Comment: Yes, so for achieving that you have to observe the auth state from component, it would be the better approach rather than using toast in your store.

Comment: It would be more ideal to observe the store actions or state change. I would write a plugin to accomplish this as described in the docs of Pinia itself.

Subscribe to actions :https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html#Subscribing-to-actions

Subscribe to state: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#Subscribing-to-the-state

Write a plugin: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html

"This is useful to add global objects like the router, modal, or toast managers."